# How to allow only numeric value in DataGridview cell in VC++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, datagridview

I have a DataGridView of a winform. And I want to allow only numeric values in a particular  column. I have searched on internet also but not getting relevant information about it.

Can anybody tell me how i can give only numeric functionality to dataGridview column.

Thanks